# rewrite rule for php url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

hello I have this url `http://localhost/index.php?a=group&name=groupname`
I would like it to look like `http://localhost/group/groupname`
where a= is dynamic and name same thing.For htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/groupname/?$ /index.php?a=$1&name=groupname [QSA,NC,L]
```

This will rewrite :

- http://example.com/foo/groupname

to

- http://example.com/index.php?a=foo&name=groupname

Edit :

If the **groupname** is also dynmic, then in the patten, just replace **groupname** with **([^/]+)** and replace **name=groupname** with **name=$2** in the target path.

Comment: would it keep the /foo/groupname ?

Comment: I need both group and groupname to be variables. not groupname as constant

Comment: sorry it didnt work RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?a=$1&nme=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

Comment: @Fogsy
 What url are you going to? and where is the htaccess located?

Comment: htaccess is on /www/html  and url i go to is site.com/group/thegroupname

Comment: Perhaps rewrite module is not enabled on your server.

Comment: its enabled . RewriteRule ^lang/spanish$ index.php?lang=spanish  [L] this works fine but yours doesnt ;/

Comment: @Fogsy I think your other rules are conflicting with this . Can you post your htaccess in the question?

Comment: @Fogsy what happens when you go to /group/groupname? Do you get a 404 error or something els?

Comment: @Fogsy Try removing the leading slash from the Rewrite target, change **/index.php** to **index.php**